# Cannot access a website, DNS fails

Tags: domain-name-system, update

I can't access my website, the DNS fails at a certain point.

I don't understand much of this stuff, so I hope someone can give a simple answer for this **question**:
Can I fix it even if it is a temporary solution? How?

I believe these questions are the exact thing that is happening to me

- [Dns failing to propagate worldwide](https://serverfault.com/questions/42678/dns-failing-to-propagate-worldwide)
- [Why did this website dns change fail in some parts of the us](https://serverfault.com/questions/103281/why-did-this-website-dns-change-fail-in-some-parts-of-the-us)

C:\> tracert ryuushin.net

```
1 192.168.1.1
2 201.67.130.254
3 201.10.252.173
4 201.10.235.89
5 201.10.241.18
6 66.110.68.33
7 66.110.68.6
8 64.86.9.77
9 64.86.9.14
10 209.58.44.2
11 68.86.86.81
12 68.86.85.153
13 68.86.86.94
14 75.149.228.2
15 70.87.253.50
16 74.55.252.146 ( 2-1.dsr01.hstntx.theplanet.com )
17 74.55.252.82 ( p01.car06.hstntx2.theplanet.com )
18 * * * Request timed out.
19 * * * Request timed out.
...
30 * * * Request timed out.
```

If I am missing any info let me know...

**Update**:

C:\>nslookup ryuushin.net

```
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  fe80::29d3:9dff:56ed:1b1d

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out
```

**Update2**:

C:\>ping ryuushin.net

```
Pinging ryuushin.net [174.123.210.242] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 174.123.210.242:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Accessing the page

```
The connection has timed out
The server at ryuushin.net is taking too long to respond.
```

**Of note: It was working just fine until Sunday morning, when it sundently started to behave like this.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dns lookup is resolving to: 174.123.210.242

what you're doing is not dns. you are tracing the server hops to get to wherever your site is hosted.

not all servers will respond to a ping, and not all ipaddresses will resolve to a domain name

to test dns resolution use on a windows box: nslookup ryuushin.net

if this is not working in all locations, be patient, dns can take a fair while to replicate around the world.

if after 48 hours it is still failing, get in contact with your domain name host or registar.

after your update:

check this url for lookup information:
http://www.dnswatch.info/dns/dnslookup?la=en&host=+ryuushin.net&type=A&submit=Resolve

it looks like your dns on your machine is a bit funky.

that you're able to do a tracert suggests that the dns is resolving to an IP address ok.

what do you get if you just do: ping ryuushin.net

also, what do you get when you open the page in a web browser.

i get an apache config page from here, so i would suggest the issue is somewhere on your LAN.

Comment: See Update2... With a ping I get 100% packet loss, accessing the page I get that the page is taking too long to respond, the same happens to that ip address... Is it the DNS from my machine? What could I do about it?

Comment: I solved by changing the DNS from my router to Google's DNS and then rebooted the router. I will accept your answer because it helped me to understand a bit more and helped me to find the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update it looks like there is indeed a DNS issue but your first problem is to determine at what point that error is, because it might just as easily be on your own machine. Start systematically eliminating links in the chain. Start at the DNS server, checking firstly that you do in fact have the correct entries, and work back to your machine until the lookup fails.

Answer (score 0):

Your web site and the DNS servers are all on the same subnet (174.123.210.242 - 244).  This is a single point of failure.

That network had some connectivity issues (I can't reproduce them now) so not only did your site stop responding, but for some the domain would have stopped resolving too.   This would also cause inbound e-mail to bounce instead of queue.

Invest in some diverse DNS hosting, so that your DNS continues to work even if the main web hosting goes down.  A google search for "secondary DNS provider" should reveal plenty.